# Sombrero Winter Bash 011

Tags: soporte, winterbash-2016

Hoy he conseguido mi 11º sombrero pero no he recibido el sombrero 011, cuyo requisito es obtener 11 sombreros. Me ha parecido un poco raro ya que han pasado unas cuantas horas desde que he obtenido el 11º y no me lo han dado.

[Web de sombreros](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/)

¿Hay algún requisito extra para este sombrero? ¿o se trata de un bug?

Comment: Me parece que necesitas ganar 11 sombreros en un sitio para ganar este sombrero. No lo puedo confirmar feacientemente, pero viendo el [leaderboard](https://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) de sombreros, para nuestro sitio solo 2 personas tienen el sombrero 011 y tienen 11 sombreros en [main]. A diferencia tuya, que posees 11 sombreros pero no todos son de un sitio en particular.

Comment: Muchas gracias @LuiggiMendoza intentaré conseguir los 11 sombreros en el mismo sitio  y confirmaré  si es así

Comment: He podido comprobar que esto se cumple consiguiendo los 11 en el mismo sitio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedo confirmar lo que comenta Luiggi: necesitas haber ganado 11 sombreros *en un mismo sitio* para obtener el sombrero "011" (en ese mismo sitio). La verdad es que la descripción no es muy clara.

Comment: Muchas gracias por comprobarlo, la verdad es que la descripción no es muy clara